# What type of plant is this in the Arizona desert?

Tags: identification, shrubs, desert

I want to identify this plant. It's located in Phoenix and appears to be a shrub.

[image]

Comment: It could be useful if you add more picture, at least one zoomed on the stems.

Comment: Agree, more pictures with better light, showing detail of foliage as well as a clearer version of this photo.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a wild guess:
To me it looks like a Tumbleweed of the Salsola spcies.
It was my first impression considerinfy you mentioned Arizona desert. Googeling it shows a couple of pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The image is blurry sure, but to me this looks like a young Fennel plant. Fennel grows really well in typical drought conditions. A tell tale sign would be the aroma coming from it. Once matured, it produces beautifully florets of yellow flowers and attracts all manners of insects.

Do post a better picture, or try smelling the plant from a safe distance (if you touch it, wash your hands till you are certain of the species).

Answer (score 1):

Could this also be [tamarix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamarix)? Also called *Salt Cedar*, it's considered invasive in some parts of the world. Some people here are trying to [get rid of them](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/31157/14120).

But some are also beautiful in the spring for they come all pink:
[image]

definitely add some close up pictures and spring pictures.