# I'm trying to get rid of the tamarisk on my property

Tags: pest-control, yard

Lately, many salt cedars (tamarisk) are growing on my property. I'm trying to get rid of them, but I don't want to hurt any of my other plants. It seems they're grown to a field in size. They are scattered all over, and I need ways to  dispose of them. There are too many to be killed  manually and I'm wondering if there is anything I can do to get rid of them but not kill any of the other wild life. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The best way I know is continuous digging them up where you do not want them to take hold.  Pulling baby seedlings when you see them.  You will never be able to eradicate them from your yard.  This plant would be involved in some statewide eradication effort IF it weren't for the habitat it provides...some bird.  Can't remember but the animal is protected.  It is valuable for EROSION control, so if you live with slopes you should think about keeping a thick 'sweep' of it on the steepest parts of the slope above your home while pulling all the little ones popping up.  It also, sucks up water like nobodies' business, another great attribute if you are living on a slope, or  at the foot of slopes!  It does minimize all other indigenous plants using a toxin, so you'll be able to maintain a group or sweep of them to work for  you and your property.  And they are a pretty plant planted in mass. Check out this site;[park service help](https://www.nps.gov/sagu/learn/nature/tamarisk.htm)  These people will identify and give you the best ways to either eradicate or manage.  I ASSUME you live in Arizona, Phoenix!!!  I was born in Tucson, my kids live down there.  I miss the desert!!

Comment: Hi Stormy, It looks like the link you gave is kind of a trick, or malformed (so my web browser says)

Comment: @J.Chomel Weirdness!  Try this one, I am sorry. "Trick"??? https://www.nps.gov/sagu/learn/nature/tamarisk.htm

Comment: That one's better. I edited your post accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

For my part, I would collect a huge amount of mulch and cover the yard with it. You won't need to bend to do the job, just shovel and carts.

This will allow lots of wildlife to inhabit below there, and help retain water when it falls. This could represent lots of mulch, depending on the surface you have to cover, though.